# Team Foundation Server - Branching

Tags: .net, tfs

I was asked to make a branch in a project i'm working on.

I'm using Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio Pro 2008 with the Team Explorer.

In Source Control Explorer, i created a branch of a test project and checked in the files.

the problem is that in Solution Explorer, doing the Get Latest Version, i don't see the branch project.

I think i'm not doing this correctly, any help would be appreciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

I completely misread the problem. As eFloh suggested in the comments, your problem is that you have not added the files to your solution. Branching only involves copying the files on the file system, it does not affect the solutions/projects themselves. Your new branch will have its own project file and you will need to add this project to the existing solution or open it in its own solution.

**Original Answer:**

There are a couple places you could be going wrong, but I suspect you might be mis-understanding how a branch is intended to work.

How to do it:
If you have a project, say $/ProjectA, that want to branch to a location under $/Reasearch/, you would right-click ProjectA in Source Control and select "Branch". In the Target field of the branch dialog, Browse/enter $/Research/. This will then create a linked copy of ProjectA under Research. It sounds like you already managed this.

What it does:
This copies the current version of ProjectA to the new location under Research. You can now make changes to your Research branch and check them in and **these changes will not affect your original code-line**.

Merging:
If you make changes under your Research branch and want to bring these changes back to the original project, you must Merge them. To do this (after checking in all changes), right-click on your $/Research/ProjectA branch and select "Merge". Use this dialog to configure your merge and this will copy all differences back to your original branch.

Comment: just to clarify: A branch is a "copy" of a whole project including its solution [1], so you will never see a branch in the solution explorer, but only in the source control explorer.
[1] this is part of the truth, but correct for your case. See the TFS branching and merging guide [link](http://tinyurl.com/467lagc)

Comment: Yes, I definitely misread that Nuno was looking in the Solution Explorer. I mistakenly thought he said he wasn't seeing something in the Source Control Explorer. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: So, i have to add the branch project i created in Source Control Explorer to a new Solution or add it to the Solution i have now. Thanks for the help.